# Property 'x' is private and only accessible within class 'y'

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic2

I have this piece of code:

```
   import { Component } from '@angular/core';
    import { NavController, Loading, Alert } from 'ionic-angular';

    @Component({
      templateUrl: 'build/pages/search/search.html',
    })

    export class SearchPage {
    constructor (....)
    {
         // code here
    }

    findItems()
    {
            let loading = Loading.create({
                content: "Finding items..."
            });

            this.nav.present(loading);
            // other stuff here
    }
```

When I run `ionic serve` everything shows correctly but when I click a button which calls `findItems()` method I get this error:

```
Error TS2341: Property 'create' is private and only accessible within class 'Loading
```

An analogous errors appears if I do:

```
let alert = Alert.create({
                    title: 'Hello!',
                });
```

In this case in my terminal appears following message:`Error TS2341: Property 'create' is private and only accessible within class 'Alert'.`

I'm working with Ionic2 version 2.0.0-beta.36

Comment: Are you using `Ionic beta 11` or a previous version? You can see that by taking a look at your `package.json` and finding something like `"ionic-angular": "^2.0.0-beta.11",`

Comment: @sebaferreras  in package.json I have: "ionic-angular": "2.0.0-beta.10"

Comment: Hmm everything seems to be working properly. Could you please take a look at [this plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/0kIk7z?p=preview)?

Comment: @splunk you may want to update your post to reflect that you're using beta 10. My answer was based on the fact that you have beta 36 listed in your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDIT:** This only applies to beta 11 and higher

This is because `create` is a [private](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/classes.html#public-private-and-protected-modifiers) function of the class `Loading`, and therefore not callable outside of the `Loading` class.

The [code example](http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/components/#loading) from Ionic's documentation shows a `LoadingController` class used to instantiate the Loading object with the desired options. I would start there.

```
import { LoadingController }  from 'ionic-angular';

//...

constructor(private loadingController: LoadingController) {

}

findItems() {
  let loading = this.loadingController.create({
  content: "Finding items..."
  duration: 3000
  });

  loading.present();
  // other stuff here
}
```

Comment: `LoadingController` was introduced in `Ionic beta 11`. I'm not sure if the code from the OP uses that version or `Ionic beta 10`.

Comment: @sebaferreras He explicitly says he's using beta 36 in his post. Looks like he's actually using beta 10 though based on his comment.

Comment: The latest version is `beta 11` so that's maybe the `cli version` or something else. In one of the comments the user said that the `ionic-angular` version is `beta 10`.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the syntax for [Alerts](http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/components/#alert) has changed. Here's the new syntax:

```
import { AlertController } from 'ionic-angular';

export class MyPage {
  constructor(private alertController: AlertController){
  }

  showAlert() {
    let alert = this.alertController.create({
      title: 'New Friend!',
      subTitle: 'Your friend, Obi wan Kenobi, just accepted your friend request!',
      buttons: ['OK']
    });
    alert.present();
  }
}
```