# Property 'readFiles' is private and only accessible within class 'ImageUploadDirective'

Tags: angular

in my angular 2 project when i run npm run build:prod i got an error.can any one suggest seed project for mean 2.0 (Angular and nodejs)

```
Property 'readFiles' is private and only accessible within class 'ImageUploadDirective'.
```

my appmodule.ts is

```
 import { ImageUploadDirective, ImageUploadModule } from 'ng2-imageupload';

    import { MapComponent } from './map/mapComponent';
   import { AgmCoreModule } from 'angular2-google-maps/core';

    import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
    import { routing } from './app.routing';
    @NgModule({
        declarations: [
            AppComponent,
            MapComponent,
            Add_address,Add_City,Add_District,Add_sub_urbans
             ],

        imports: [AgmCoreModule.forRoot({
              apiKey: "Key",
              libraries: ["places"]
                }),
                 BrowserModule,
                ImageUploadModule,


                ],

        providers:[ApiMessageService,RealEstateService],

        bootstrap: [AppComponent]
    })
    export class AppModule {

    }
```

Comment: Error message is as detailed as it could be. You should not access private fields.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Property 'x' is private and only accessible within class 'y'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38837964/property-x-is-private-and-only-accessible-within-class-y)

Comment: i didn't use like readFiles property in my project